# WCF Formatter extensibilty point, with XmlSerializerFormat?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

Is there a way, I can intercept into WCF serialization process, when using XmlSerializer?

Can't migrate to using DataContract Serialization, right away. Thus I am looking for some `common place` where all the magic will happen.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into Message Inspectors which provide a commonly used extension point.

The following links provide good overview information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

Comment: Message Inspectors, are place where object gets already converted into xml, I am looking to hook into serialization process itself.

Answer (score 2):

One potential consideration is to decorate the message which is serialized with Attributes.

You might find this helpful...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx

Comment: I need to determine `Which attribute has to be included in serialization` during runtime, based on some business logic.

Comment: So in this case decorating properties with attributes will not help us.

Comment: Is there an example you can provide to provide more clarity? Based on information you have provided so far (that you need to "change" the message at run time)  it seems like message inspector would be a better solution.